# Achieving a CSS curvature between vertical and horizontal divs?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a titlebar and left-side panel using `div`'s and `css`, but as in the screenshot below,

- is it possible to create a curvature using `css`, similar to the red
  curvature I've drawn with `paintbrush`?
- You'll also notice a visible blue colour difference between
  the yellow arrows. Is it possible to have a more uniform gradient?
  I'd like a uniform gradient on the vertical and horizontal panels.
- What I'm actually trying to achieve is shown in the bottom half of
  the image. A uniform panel with shadows at the edges. Is it possible
  to create using CSS or do I have no other option other than to design
  it in `GIMP` and use an image for the entire vertical and horizontal
  panel (it's hard to design in `GIMP` too)?

A jsfiddle example or a link to an existing example would help best. I'm not new to programming, but am new to `css`.

[image]

Comment: For curvature, try the `border-radius` style. The value can be between 0 and 90, with higher values making the curve steeper.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of what you've done till now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-element for that cut and apply inset `box-shadow` to achieve this.

For the text Logo, Title and Menu you could add `span`s and apply `display: inline-block` to first two `span`s.

```css
body {
  background: #C4C4FF;
}
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #8080FF;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #C4C4FF; /* This color must be same as background */
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 10px -6px #666;
}
span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
div span:nth-of-type(1),
div span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Logo</span
  ><span>Title</span>
  <span>Menu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like a familiar request to one already seen (by both you and me) from earlier today :P